# Split window on specific buffer

Tags: window-splitting

I am new to Emacs but I'm working hard to catch up :)

I try to get Emacs splits a window (with `C-x 3` for example) not on the same buffer (default behaviour) but on a specific `*dashboard*` buffer. I've read that I have to add to my configuration file this line

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice (lambda () (get-buffer "*dashboard*")))
```

from the [dashboard package documentation](https://github.com/emacs-dashboard/emacs-dashboard) or even this line

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice #'(lambda () (get-buffer-create "*dashboard*")))
```

form this [page](http://sodaware.sdf.org/notes/showing-emacs-dashboard/).

I have a `myinit.org` file which I include from my `init.el` file with this piece of code to load the dashboard package :

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
    (use-package dashboard
      :ensure t
      :init
      (progn
        (setq dashboard-items '((recents . 4)
                    (projects . 3)
                    (bookmarks . 3)))
        (setq dashboard-show-shortcuts nil)
        (setq dashboard-set-heading-icons t)
        (setq dashboard-set-file-icons t)
        (setq dashboard-startup-banner "~/.emacs.d/emacs_logo.png")
        (setq initial-buffer-choice #'(lambda () (get-buffer-create "*dashboard*"))))
        ;(setq initial-buffer-choice (lambda () (get-buffer "*dashboard*"))))
      :config
      (dashboard-setup-startup-hook))
    ;(setq initial-buffer-choice (lambda () (get-buffer "*dashboard*"))))
    
  #+END_SRC
```

None of the different options I used to place this line (as you can see with the commented lines) is working. I have even try to add this line directly to my `init.el` file without success. I have *always* the `*dashboard*` buffer when I open Emacs but when I type `C-x 3` for example, it still opens a window with the same buffer...

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong here ?
Thanks in advance,
Sylvain

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to accomplish.
Do you want to split a buffer and the new one be other different buffer? 
Do you want to split the dashboard buffer and modify that buffer in the split?
If you can clarify these points, I'll try to help. Thak you